# Shortcode for order number

Tags: shortcode

I need a shortcode for the order number of WC order.
I'm trying to build a custom thankyou page where I would like to add the ordernumber.

The code the fetch the order number seems to be get_order_number(); ?>. But how can I create a shortcode for this? Can someone help please?